# "IF" expression syntax clarification

Tags: excel, office365

Really simple for someone with more Excel experience than me.

Logically I need my formula to output the result of this:

```
IF Cell G2 contains "Y", then display the value of Cell E2
```

How on earth do I do it!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=If(CountIf(G2,"*y*")>0,E2,"")`

This checks the cell `G2` for a `y`. If there's a `y` *anywhere* in the cell, it'll return `E2`'s value. Otherwise, blank.

If you wanted to search for words starting with "y", just remove the first wildcard and search for `"y*"`.  Vice versa for words that end in "Y", you'd use `"*y"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,"Y")), E2, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` statement works like this:

`=IF(Test, Value if Test = True, Value if Test = False)`

So the formula you need is:

`=IF(G2="Y", E2, "")`

Comment: Careful - OP asked if a cell contains "Y". It's not clear if it will *only* have "Y" or if it will be anywhere in there (like in "this is my text").  This will work if the cell only has "Y".

Comment: @BruceWayne Good point, my assumption is that they are testing for a "Y" in a cell that is simply a Yes / No field characterised by only Y / N